# currying: How to make first input as optional?

Tags: scala

I am learning `Scala` and concept of `currying`. This is what I am doing

```
scala> def div(a:Int)(b:Int) = a/b
div: (a: Int)(b: Int)Int

scala> div(10)(2)
res9: Int = 5

scala> val d = div(10)_
d: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> d(5)
res10: Int = 2

scala> val e = div _ (2)
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '(' found.
       val e = div _ (2)
                     ^

scala>
```

**Question**
- How can I make `a` as optional and not `b`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fix `b` and get a function `Int => Int`, but you need to keep the parentheses, and unfortunately annotate the type:

```
scala> div(_: Int)(2)
res7: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> res7(10)
res8: Int = 5

scala> res7(2)
res9: Int = 1
```

`a` isn't "optional", it's just a parameter in the resulting function.